# Find lines starting with "t", continue with a vowel and total length 4

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file with containing 300+ words. I need to find lines starting with "t", continue with a vowel and total length of 4. Then i need to convert them in to a format where each line have one word.

```
tr -s "[[:blank:]]" "\n" < file | grep .
```

With this I'm able to format the file but i cant figure out how can i select words with the requirement above. I'm stuck :/

i.e. i have a file that includes "terra train chair tol mourn". i need to format this file like this:

```
tera  
train  
chair  
tola  
mourn
```

and find the ones starting with a "t" and continue with a vowel with total length of 4. so out should be like this:

```
tera 
tola
```

Comment: give sample file data and expected output

Comment: added a sample to the question.

Comment: terra length is 5 and tol is 3 so they may not be selected

Comment: Yeah you are right, sorry for the inconvenience i corrected the sample.

Comment: thanks for adding info as requested and good job formatting it as well :) can you clarify few more points? does input file have only single word per line? only consists of alphabets or can contain other characters as well? are there trailing spaces?

Comment: Kind Stranger's answer was the one I'm looking for. But since I am currently a newbie in bash, I've figured out that answer only "prints" the words. So how can I print the output of that commend to a new file, or change the original file with that commend's output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can use grep for this.  If you just need the first word from a line:

```
grep -Eow '^t[aeiou]\S{2}' file > formatted_file
```

If you need to match the whole line:

```
grep -Eow '^t[aeiou]\S{2}$' file > formatted_file
```

- `^` achors the search to the start of the line.
- `t` matches exactly the letter "t".
- `[aeiou]` matches any one of the characters between `[` and `]`.
- `\S{2}` matches 2 non-whitespace characters
- `$` matches the end of a line
- `-w` means grep will only match whole words which in effect limits your search to the exact number of characters specified in `PATTERN`.
- `-o` means you only output the exact match found (in this case, your 4 letter word)

**EDIT**

Can also use the `-i` option if you want `grep` to ignore case (uppercase/lowercase)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the perfect explanation. The silly thing is that I've discovered that my input file does not contain any of the word with given pattern. So I'm gonna change the input file :D

Comment: Since I am currently a newbie in bash, I've figured out that answer only "prints" the words. So how can I print the output of that commend to a new file, or change the original file with that commend's output?

Comment: @OğulcanÇelik you can reroute the standar output and write to a file as I've shown above.  Use `> formatted_file` after the command to get it to write the output to `formatted_file`

Comment: We can use the `-x` option as well to match the whole line.

Answer (score 1):

Following perl oneliner

```
perl -nle 'push @A,$_ for /\bt[aeiou]..\b/gi;END{print"@A"}' <file
```

It was not clear if one input line may have many words or if all the words of output should be on one line.

```
perl -nle 'print for /\bt[aeiou]..\b/gi' <file
```

Following updates grep is sufficient for this work

```
grep -i '^t[eaiou][a-z][a-z]$' <file
```